# How can i see my ranked 5v5 team's elo even though it is not ranked?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am in a 5v5 ranked team and I discovered that you can't see the elo of it, after playing 3 games.
But just like in solo queue, there must an estimated elo ranking.

Does anybody know where i can find this?

Answer (score 3):

Go to [lolking.net](http://lolking.net)

Search for your Summoner Name and Under Tab Personal Ratings you will find columns called:

```
Team 3v3, Team 5v5
```

There you will see the name of your team and its rating.

My team has 0 games this season but I can see the rating. So it should work.

Comment: Note that this only shows the elo of the highest elo team you're on.

Answer (score 0):

Something that you must know before you check your stats - first few ranked games are not shown because of [Elo rating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) specific. With so few data about team **the value is inaccurate and misleading so don't care about it** too much!

You can check such data for example;

1. L̶o̶l̶b̶a̶s̶e̶ ̶-̶ ̶F̶r̶e̶e̶
2. [Lolking](http://lolking.net/) - Free
3. L̶o̶l̶s̶t̶a̶t̶i̶s̶t̶i̶c̶s̶ ̶-̶ ̶F̶r̶e̶e̶
4. E̶l̶o̶b̶u̶f̶f̶ ̶-̶ ̶P̶a̶i̶d̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶

Elo shines after 20 or more games. So keep on playing!

Comment: LoL doesn't use the Elo System, it uses an *undisclosed* variation of it. (Also, nearly all of your links are dead.)